# Pegar seletor de elemento criado em tempo de execução

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, query

Tenho um sistema que listo os campos e atributos de uma tabela através de javascript e ajax até ai tudo, só que os elementos criados e listados em tempo de execução preciso manipula lós através de um seletor como faço pra pegar esse seletor como o id ?

Este é o código que utilizo pra exibir os campos:

```
    if($_POST['op']=='bancopesquisartabelas'){  
    $pdo = new PDO(DB_SERVER.":host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".$_POST['bancotabelas'],DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SHOW TABLES FROM ".$_POST['bancotabelas']);
    $sql->execute();    
    foreach($sql as $obj){
        echo '<option value="'.$obj[0].'">'.$obj[0].'</option>';
 }  $pdo = null;

 } else if ($_POST['op']=='mostarcampos'){

 $_SESSION['bancotabelas']=$_POST['bancotabelas'];
 $_SESSION['tabelasbanco']=$_POST['tabelasbanco']; 

       $pdo = new PDO(DB_SERVER.":host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".$_POST['bancotabelas'],DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
       $sql = $pdo->prepare("SHOW FIELDS FROM ".$_POST['tabelasbanco']); 
       $sql->execute();
       foreach($sql as $obj){  
    echo'
        <input id="'.$obj[0].'" type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$obj[0].'" placeholder="'.$obj[0].'" style="width:150px">
        <input id="'.$obj[1].'" type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$obj[1].'" placeholder="'.$obj[1].'" style="width:150px">
        <input id="'.$obj[2].'" type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$obj[2].'" placeholder="'.$obj[2].'" style="width:150px">
        <input id="'.$obj[3].'" type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$obj[3].'" placeholder="'.$obj[3].'" style="width:150px">
        <input id="'.$obj[4].'" type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$obj[4].'" placeholder="'.$obj[4].'" style="width:150px">
        <input id="'.$obj[5].'" type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$obj[5].'" placeholder="'.$obj[5].'" style="width:150px">
        <button id="updatetabela" class="btn btn-default">Alterar</button>      
    ';
   }
}
```

através dele seleciono o banco e a tabela e ele lista pra mim seus campos e atributos preciso pegar o id deles quando estão criados para disparar um evento com o botão e poder alterar a tabela, desde já agradeço a ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esse ID ai que quero pegar quando escolho o banco e a tabela ele é gerado.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas dá para deixar os botões com o mesmo nome e adicionar o id que você quer pegar, no caso ali você estava deixando os id's iguais o que não é correto, pois id tem que ser único, name pode repetir, em todos os seus inputs também está a repetir  o id isso é errado, funciona, mas é errado isso,  Ex:

```
<button name="updatetabela" id="'.$obj[0].'" class="btn btn-default">Alterar</button>
```

Assumindo que está usando Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button[name=updatetabela]').click(function(){
         console.log(this.id);
    });
});
```